# How to match email and password from local storage for a registration app in angular

Tags: angular7

I have stored name , age, email and password in local storage from a sign up form, now at SignIn page I'm taking email and password as Input and I want to match these credentials from local storage. I am new to programming languages so I want you to help me out in this scenario.

Comment: Provide the relevant code that you have worked to set and get items in localstorage..

Comment: Hi @ManirajfromKarur **Thanks** for replying, but I have alredy solved it.  `var localArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('users')); for (let i = 0; i < localArray.length; i++) { if(localArray[i].NuserEmail == this.userEmail && localArray[i].NuserPass == this.userPass){ this.router.navigate(['/user-profile'], { queryParams: { uuid: localArray[i].uuid } }) } else { console.log("Wrong Credentials"); } }`